# How do I unlock all of the stages in Smash Bros for Wii U?

Tags: wii-u, super-smash-bros-4

I noticed that I unlocked some stages when I unlocked characters, but other stages also seem to unlock when clearing certain event matches. I haven't gotten a message saying that all stages are available, so I assume there are others I haven't found yet. What do I have to do to unlock each stage?

Comment: Some challenges unlock stages, so there's that...

Answer (score 8):

The requirements to unlock each stage can be found in [this blog post](http://www.superabxy.com/blog/2014/11/19/how-to-unlock-all-characters-and-stages-in-super-smash-bros-for-wii-u):

> - **Kongo Jungle 64**: Clear the "The Original Heavy Weights" event in Event Match (single player).
> - **Smashville**: Clear the "Playing Tricks" event in Event Match (single player).
> - **Pokemon Stadium 2**: Clear the "Lightning Strikes" event in Event Match (single player).
> - **PAC-LAND**: Play all the maps in Smash Tour.
> - **Flat Zone X**: Play alone as Mr. Game & Watch and destroy 100 blocks in a single game of Trophy Rush.
> - **Duck Hunt**: Get one or more KOs in a single Solo Cruel Smash.

I have confirmed all of these methods and that these are all of the unlockable stages.

Comment: For Flat Zone X, is that a 100-combo, or is that just 100 cumulative?

Comment: It's just 100 cumulative. The challenge (on the challenge board) is worded differently from challenges that require chains.