# How do you unlock the Stage Switch?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

I was just watching a Smash 4 stream where the player actually had the option to disable specific stages when choosing randomly, like existed in previous versions of Smash Bros.

**I want that.**

How can I unlock that feature?

Comment: In melee you had to unlock all the stages first - Its likely the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply have to unlock all of the stages.

Comment: See this question to see how to unlock all of the stages: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192706/how-do-i-unlock-all-of-the-stages-in-smash-bros-for-wii-u

Comment: For those who wonder: No, you don't need all of the DLC-Stages for it to work ;)